# I'm having problems assigning values to an array I created in vb. Seems really simple but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: arrays, vb.net

So I created an n x 2 array to hold some figures I would be inputting at runtime. Then I went ahead to add code which would add the values to the array. I wanted to know if the array was populated properly so I added code to populate a listbox with each figure inputted. However I don't think the array is populating as I think it should because the listbox isn't updating. The relevant code section is below;

```
     N_secteion = txtNumSections.Text
     Dim input_info(,) As Double = New Double(N_secteion - 1), 1) {}
        Dim intIndexGrade As Integer
        Dim intIndexLength As Integer

        For intIndexGrade = 1 To N_secteion - 1
            input_info(intIndexGrade - 1, 0) = Grade(intIndexGrade)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(input_info(intIndexGrade - 1, 0).ToString())
        Next
```

Grade(intIndexGrade) extracts values from another listbox on the form as the loop continues. This doesn't seem to be a problem since I've monitored it and it seems to pick up these values just fine. I would really appreciate some help. Been at this for too long.

Comment: You shouldn't have to guess if things are working as they should or not and you shouldn't have to output data to ensure that it was initially set or that it's values are what you expect. For things like this you'd use the built in debugger in visual studio. It would allow you to simply inspect the array variable and see what data it contains, if any. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Anu6is, so I actually did use the watch window to monitor the array variable by putting the break point at "Next" and as a result for the first loop, at intIndexGrade = 1, I was able to monitor that the array variable did output the right value. Then I put the break point just below "Next" which meant that the loop would have completed. This is where I noticed that the array variable was outputting a "0" even though the Grade(intIndexGrade) was producing the right value so it should just have assigned this to the array variable.

Comment: I suggest you use `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On`. It'll light up a couple places which could be improved upon, and by doing so you might just correct your problem inadvertently.

Comment: For an example, in `N_secteion = txtNumSections.Text` you're probably getting a number, but in String type. At least later you're using it as an Integer: `For intIndexGrade = 1 To N_secteion - 1`. This should be done explicitly, even if just to make sure that it works as intended, while right now it's being converted implicitly, which sometimes cause unexpected behavior in an application.

Comment: @Anu6is, okay never mind. I just figured out how to solve the problem. Cheers.

Comment: @laancelot. Thank you for your comments. I managed to make it work.

Comment: @DaVince294 You should post your solution as an answer and check it, so a future user having a similar issue can find it and profit from your experience.

Comment: @laancelot. Ah! I see. I'm new to this platform. I'll post it right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
    N_secteion = txtNumSections.Text
    Dim input_info(,) As Double = New Double((N_secteion - 1), 1) {}
    Dim intIndexGrade As Integer
    Dim intIndexLength As Integer

    For intIndexGrade = 1 To N_secteion
        input_info(intIndexGrade - 1, 0) = Grade(intIndexGrade)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(input_info(intIndexGrade - 1, 0).ToString())
    Next
```

So the issue was I wasn't looping through intIndexGrade enough times. Once this was corrected, the ListBox began to populate with all the values of the array variable because it only did so once the loop was complete.